# How can I hide form fields (city & state) until zip is populated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I hide form field (both city and state) until the zip field is populated?

I am using a geo based program to auto-populate the city and state based on zip code and I don't want the city and state fields to even show until the data has populated.

My html code (just for the two fields) are as follows.  Please let me know if you need more of my code.  Just don't want to weigh the site down.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-left">State *</div>
    <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="state" name="state" class="form-input" value="FL" /></div>
    <div class="form-error"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-left">Zip Code *</div>
    <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" class="form-input" value="33574" /></div>
    <div class="form-error"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: `stateInput.style.display = (zipInput.value.length > 0) ? "block" : "none";`

Comment: Better idea: allow the user to fill in city and state, but if zip code is entered *and* those two fields are blank, *then* auto-populate them. Besides, what if your user doesn't know the zip code?

Comment: @Blazemonger -  The user wouldn't know the zipcode for their own address?

Comment: You didn't say what addresses are being entered. I know my own zip code, but rarely remember anyone else's. (Sometimes I even get a brain f*rt and forget my own zip code, but never the city, because it's easier to memorize one word than five numbers.) Regardless, it's always better to give your users *more* choices for inputting data than to take choices away without a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example using jQuery.
HTML - Added  and 'id' to div containing input text and hidden attribute set to true initially

```
    <div id="stateContainer" class="row" hidden="true">
    <div class="form-left">State *</div>
    <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="state" name="state" class="form-input" value="FL" /></div>
    <div class="form-error"></div>
</div>
<div id="zipCodeContainer" class="row">
    <div class="form-left">Zip Code *</div>
    <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" class="form-input" value=""  /></div>
    <div class="form-error"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#zip').change(function(){
    if($('#zip').val() !== ''){
        $('#stateContainer').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML you have provided, the following code can toggle the fields based on the zip code input. 
jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/q78bj/)

```
 var $zip = $("#zip");
ToggleFields(); //Toggle based on initial state
$zip.on("change",function(){
    ToggleFields();
});

function ToggleFields(){        
    if($zip.val()){ //Check if there is zip code present
        if($zip.val().length != 5){
            $("#city").closest("div.row").hide();
            $("#state").closest("div.row").hide();       
        }else{
            $("#city").closest("div.row").show();
            $("#state").closest("div.row").show();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I've tried the code, but it won't seem to hide the fields.....I placed it up on a test page....online.saintleo.edu/ZIPCODE%20(ORIGINAL)%20-%20Copy.html

Answer (score 0):

check it on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RBby9/)

```
   $('#zip').change(function(){
    if($('#zip').val() !== ''){
        $('#stateContainer').show();
    }
   });
```

Comment: Okay I've tried the code, but it won't seem to hide the fields.....I placed it up on a test page....http://online.saintleo.edu/ZIPCODE%20(ORIGINAL)%20-%20Copy.html

Comment: are writing it within the $(document).ready() function , if not than place it inside ready function

Comment: I see, thank you, Qasim.  1.) Now it is triggering the state field, which is good, but I would like the city field to also be hidden until the zip is keyed. I tried to use the same div id but it didn't work. 2.) Is it also possible to have the fields "toggle" when the zip is removed?  3.) How do you make the fields clear when the page is reloaded? So that someone on a local computer doesn't see the previous info?  Thanks for all of your help!  http://online.saintleo.edu/ZIPCODE%20(ORIGINAL)%20-%20Copy.html

Comment: yes you can there is an hide() function , which can be used within else block.

Comment: Qasim,  How do I get the city field to also hide like we did with the state field?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the blur handler :

Javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" onblur="myFunction(this)" class="form-input" value="33574" />
<script>
    function myFunction(that) {
        //Zip is filled ?
        if( that.value.trim() !== '' ) {
            //Show your stuff
        }
        else {
            //hide your stuff
        }
    }
</script>
```

JQuery:

```
// When you leave state/zip input
$('#zip').blur(function() {

    //Zip is filled ?
    if( $.trim($(this).val()) !== '' ) {
       //Show your stuff
    }
    else {
        //hide your stuff
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could achieve something similar using HTML5 and CSS3.

First the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mZ26q/

Markup:

```
<input type='text' pattern='^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$' id='zip' placeholder="Zip code" required />
<input type='text' id='city' placeholder="Fetching City ..." />
<input type='text' id='state' placeholder="Fetching State ..." />
```

CSS:

```
#zip:valid ~ #state,
#zip:valid ~ #city {
    display: block;
}

#zip ~ #state,
#zip ~ #city {
    display: none;
}
```

The major downside is compatibility with browsers (no support, maybe vendor prefixes?, etc.)

Comment: Okay I've tried the code, but it won't seem to hide the fields.....I placed it up on a test page....online.saintleo.edu/ZIPCODE%20(ORIGINAL)%20-%20Copy.html